# Azure CDN - Dynamic URL Path rewrite

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I want to rewrite URLs for my static API to match the accordingly named files on my blob storage (at the moment static website with `$web` directory, files are in `/api` folder), e.g.:

```
/api/universities --> /api/universities.json
/api/universities/1 --> /api/universities/1.json
```

I have tried configuring a CDN Rule for it. But I can't get it to work, anyone who can help? Docs are really thin on variables for URL Rewriting with Azure CDN. 
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? I'm struggling with a similar case

Comment: Nope, asked the support for help. They said it's not possible. But you can set it manually.

Comment: Is it not possible make it work with regex or wildcards. is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant and I have to write some more text so that's stackoverflow accepts this comment.